# how is the output 7, it should much more than that

Tags: java, methods, indexof

How is the output 7? It should be more than that.

```
public class MyClass {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String txt = "Please locate where 'locate' occurs!";
    System.out.println(txt.indexOf("locate"));
  }
}
```

Comment: Why should it be more? Can you quote some documentation or something to show why you think so? The word "locate" does appear starting at index 7.

Comment: All programmers need to learn to debug their code in order to understand why it gives unexpected results whenever it does, in fact, give unexpected results. Every good IDE these days includes a debugger. You should learn to use yours.

Comment: Indexing start from 0 and don't forget to count the whitespace as well. If you follow this, "locate" starts from index 7.

Answer (score 0):

It is obviously 7, the right answer.

> The indexOf() method returns the position of the first occurrence of
> specified character(s) in a string.

locate word occures at 7th index, as index starts from 0.

Answer (score 0):

This is how Java will return the index of your desired keyword : 
(index = 0)P
(index = 1)l
(index = 2)e
(index = 3)a
(index = 4)s
(index = 5)e
(index = 6)' '
(index = 7)locate where 'locate' occurs!